# insertion sort - syntax question

Tags: java, syntax

I came across a rather peculiar shorthand notation: `A[j+1] = A[j--]`

It seems that this line does two operations: `move A[j] right and decrement j`

is it possible to break this down into individual steps to help me understand the shorthand?

Pseudo code:

```
n=A.length
for i <- 1 to n-1
    curr = A[i]
    j = i - 1
    while j >= 0 && A[j] > curr
        A[j+1] = A[j--]
    A[j+1] = curr
```

[source](http://ww0.java4.datastructures.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
int targetIndex = j + 1;
int tmp = j;
j--;
A[targetIndex] = A[tmp];
```

Note that the `targetIndex` is computed *before* anything else happens - the left hand side of the assignment operator is effectively determined before the right hand side.

However, the decrement happens *before* the assignment itself takes place, and even before the right hand array access is evaluated. You can see that in this sample code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int j = 3;
        try {
            x[j + 1] = x[j-- + 10];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Caught exception");
        }

        System.out.println(j); // Prints 2
    }
}
```

Here, you can see that `j` has been decremented even though the assignment itself can't take place.

Indeed, the same happens if we use `x[j + 10] = x[j--];` - in other words, if it's the *target* index which is out of bounds. By the time that's discovered, the decrement has already occurred.

Comment: thanks! your answer was helpful. To simplify further we can replace A[j+1] = A[j--] by A[j+1] = A[j] ; j-- ;

Comment: @Baba: No, because that won't end up decrementing `j` if there's an exception in the array access. That was the point of my example - to prove that the decrement occurs *before* the array indexing.

Answer (score 2):

Since in your example, `j` is always less than `A.length`

```
A[j+1] = A[j--];
```

Is the same as

```
int index = j + 1;
A[index] = A[j];
j = j - 1;
```

as the following program illustrates:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] A = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        int j = 2;
        A[j+1] = A[j--];

        // prints: [1, 2, 3, 3, 5]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));

    }
}
```

Comment: No it's not. I have a counterexample in my answer - if the `A[index] = A[j];` assignment fails (e.g. due to the index being out of range), then `j` won't change in your translation... whereas in reality it would have decremented.

Comment: I've undone the downvote, but I think it's clearer to talk about what the *general* translation is... it's not like the compiler is *actually* going to put the decrement after the assignment.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I didn't think it was called for in this particular question, but I may have misjudged.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I good understood your problem but if you aren't sure j-- notation try my example. Shows difference between --j and j-- it can help you in the future:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int j = 10;
    System.out.println("Current=" + j);
    System.out.println(j--);
    System.out.println("Current=" + j);
    System.out.println(--j);
    System.out.println("Current=" + j);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Current=10
10
Current=9
8
Current=8
```